# Modify RegEx to match both hostname and port number?

Tags: c#, regex

I found this Regular Expression:

```
^(?=.{1,255}$)[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|-){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|-){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?)*\.?$
```

It's supposed to match any hostname, however I need it to also match  a colon followed by a port number at the end, like this:

```
host.name.com:8888
```

How can I modify this expression to do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the RegEx I came up with for my C# application:

```
@"^(?<hostname>((?=.{1,255}$)[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|-){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|-){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?)*\.?)|localhost)(?::(?<port>\d+))$"
```

Comment: You need to change port number part to `(?<port>\d{1,5})` because a port number cannot be longer than 5 digits.

Comment: And in case you're looking for optional port number: `^(?<hostname>((?=.{1,255}$)[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|-){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|-){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?)*\.?)|localhost)(?:(:(?<port>\d{1,5}))?)$`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex, use `TcpClient`

```
static bool checkHost(string host,int timeout)
{
    if (!host.Contains(':')) 
        return false;
    try
    {
        string[] h = host.Split(':');
        Task e = new TcpClient().ConnectAsync(h[0], int.Parse(h[1]));
        new Task(e.Start);
        Thread.Sleep(timeout);

        return e.IsCompleted;
    }
    catch (SocketException){ }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) { }

    return false;
}
```

Example

```
bool check = checkHost("google.com:80",1000);
```

Comment: This question reminds me of "What is the RegEx to validate an email address?" which usually results in someone linking http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html. As fun and cool as they are (That's just like, you opinion, man), regular expressions are often not the best way to validate destinations, i.e., email addresses, hostnames, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply change the end from $ to (?::[\d]+)?$ You can easily test such things with online reg exp matchers or [QuickREx](http://www.bastian-bergerhoff.com/eclipse/features/web/QuickREx/standalone.html), which is a tool I prefer.